# Problem during the installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my ACER GATEWAY NE46Rs

Tags: networking

I created a bootable USB using Rufus... But when I boot and select "try Ubuntu", the wifi won't connect. I have tried with an ethernet cable too but even then I can't connect to the internet.

Plus, once I click on wifi to connect, nothing seems to work thereafter. I can't even open the terminal to type the commands. I also tried with the Linux mint But was faced with the same problem...

Can I install Linux on my laptop or not?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You have the following 2 options:

1. I would suggest to go to the official ACER laptop support web portal and try to pull drivers for your laptop model for Linux in case there are any. Many laptop manufacturers now support Linux drivers since some customers don't want to overpay for having Windows preinstalled.
2. You always have an option to install Ubuntu as a Guest OS over virtual machine software, e.g. [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) but you need to have Windows as your main (host) OS installed on your laptop.